# Zip argument #2 must support iteration. Why is this error generated while reassigning the ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I have imported a dataset and trying to make separate columns of the categorical data. What is the problem here when the object passed is correct?

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
Y = dataset.iloc[:, 3].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
ct = ColumnTransformer(['encoder', OneHotEncoder(),[0]], remainder='passthrough')
X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X), dtype=np.float)
```

There is no syntax error and yet there is an error generated.

Comment: Where *exactly* does the error pop up? Please include the full trace

Comment: btw, when someone gives you an answer to your question.. it is usually the case to accept that answer or comment on it if further improvement is needed

Answer (score 0):

Check the syntax for `ColumnTransformer`. It can be quite tricky.. but the quick solution is to use this definition for `ct`

`ct = ColumnTransformer([('encoder', OneHotEncoder(),[0])], remainder='passthrough')`

Note the tuple that is defined in the list.

As you can see from the documentation (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html), the input argument `transfomers` says

Parameters:

transformers : list of tuples

Hope that makes more sense now :)